# Como fazer duas exibições em uma view com angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho um app de chat e o problema que estou tendo é o seguinte:
Ao enviar uma mensagem, ela demorando um certo tempinho pra ser enviada e aparecer na tela, pois ela vai pra um banco de dados, via backend em php que eu fiz, e depois volta por um outro php que busca a mensagem e exibe na tela.
Então uma solução que pensei, pra quebrar o galho, foi a seguinte, exibir as minhas mensagens, direto na tela, como nesse [exemplo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSOiVprDdj0) e só depois envio pro backend..
Já tenho uma tela que exibe as mensagens vindas do banco de dados, mas como fazer para exibir, nessa mesma tela, as mensagens que eu envio?

Minha view:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="mensagem in mensagens">
   <div class="item item-text-wrap">
     <h2>{{mensagem.usuario}}</h2>
     <p> {{mensagem.msg}}</p>
     <p>{{mensagem.hora}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.enviarMsgChat = function (mensagem) {
    //console.log(mensagem);
    $scope.disableButtonChat = true;

    var dia = moment().format(); //2016-02-16 T 16:05:52-02:00
    var diaP = dia.split('T');
    var dia = diaP[0];

    var horaP = diaP[1];
    var horaP2 = horaP.split(':');
    var hora = horaP2[0]+':'+horaP2[1];

    var idUsuario = $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario');
    var nome = $window.localStorage.getItem('nome');
    var usuario = $window.localStorage.getItem('usuario');
    var msgChat = {
        idUsuario: idUsuario,
        nome: nome,
        usuario: usuario,
        mensagem: mensagem,
        dia: dia,
        hora: hora
    }

    $http.post("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/www/php/enviaMsgChat.php", msgChat).then(function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        $scope.disableButtonChat = false;
        pegaMsgsChat();
        $scope.mensagem = {
          chat: ""
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: A função pegaMsgsChat() traz todas as mensagem do chat, ou somente a ultima?

Comment: Ambas... Todas e a última.

Comment: Já pensou em colocar a mensagem nova direto no seu array mensagem ? O array que está no loop é o mensagem, então o que vc deveria fazer é por a sua mensagem também no array.

Comment: Pois é @AndréVicente, mas to apanhando pra fazer isso.

Comment: Tipo $scope.mensagens.push(msgChat). Coloca a parte do código onde vc seta o array de mensagens. Se ela for global vc consegue usar na função que recebe os valores e depois usa para adicionar a nova mensagem nela.

Comment: Coloca a função `pegaMsgsChat() ` no problema que resolve isso ae rapidinho

Answer (score 0):

Pega a ultima mensagem e adiciona no final do seu vetor de mensagens do angular.

Assim:

```
$scope.enviarMsgChat = function (mensagem) {
    var idUsuario = $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario');
    var nome = $window.localStorage.getItem('nome');
    var usuario = $window.localStorage.getItem('usuario');        
    var idChat = 0;
    var dia = moment().format(); //2016-02-16 T 16:05:52-02:00
    var diaP = dia.split('T');
    var dia = diaP[0];

    var horaP = diaP[1];
    var horaP2 = horaP.split(':');
    var hora = horaP2[0]+':'+horaP2[1];

    var msgChat = {
        idChat: idChat,
        idUsuario: idUsuario,
        nome: nome,
        usuario: usuario,
        msg: mensagem,
        data: dia,
        hora: hora
    }

    $scope.mensagens.push(msgChat);

    $http.post("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/www/php/enviaMsgChat.php", msgChat).then(function (data) {
    //console.log(data);
        $scope.disableButtonChat = false;
        pegaMsgsChat();
        $scope.mensagem = {
           chat: ""
        }

    })
}
```